# Decrypt chrome cookies from sqlite db on mac os

Tags: macos, sqlite, google-chrome, encryption, pbkdf2

I use sqlite db `Cookies` from profile folder. It has `encrypted_value` field. There are a lot of examples and descriptions how it's encrypted on each platform.
So on Linux I use the following:

```
linuxPwd = 'peanuts';
var derivedKey = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(linuxPwd, 'saltysalt', 1, 16, 'sha1');
var decrypted = decrypt(derivedKey, encryptedValue);
```

And `decrypt` function:

```
function decrypt(key, encryptedData) {

var decipher, decoded, final, padding, iv = new Buffer.from(new Array(16 + 1).join(' '), 'binary');

decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-cbc', key, iv);

// Remove 'v10' from start
encryptedData = encryptedData.slice(3);
decoded = decipher.update(encryptedData);

final = decipher.final();
final.copy(decoded, decoded.length - 1);
padding = decoded[decoded.length - 1];
if (padding) decoded = decoded.slice(0, decoded.length - padding);

return decoded.toString('utf8');

}
```

So on linux password is `peanuts` (in case when no keychain is used) and number of iterations is `1`. Everything should be the same for MacOS, except number of iterations is `1003` and password is taken from keychain.

I manually got password from keychain for `Chrome Safe Storage` item and increased number of iterations:

```
macPwd = 'ELrTZt24OdPhg93BjAIJhA==';
var derivedKey = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(macPwd, 'saltysalt', 1003, 16, 'sha1');
```

It works okay on linux, decoded data is correct, but on mac I receive broken bytes. What could be wrong? Maybe I can find what argument is wrong if I know encoded string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those, who also will fall into this error. I downloaded and build chromium manually and debugged process of encryption. In some cases, when keychain is not available, the password for encryption&decryption is `mock_password`.